# can't add promoted links to new page

Tags: list, web-part, promoted-links, app-part

So I was playing around with the Promoted Links app and I figured that I could use it as a sort of work-around way to add something that would function as a categories app in terms of appearance and function. But when I go to add a Promoted Links web-part there isn't one available.

Why isn't it available and how do I get it?

Comment: do you already have a stand-alone Promoted Links app somewhere else on your site/sub-site?

Comment: I added one to a sub-site, but that sub-site is separate from the main site (no inherited permissions, basically used as a test area to play around). I haven't yet added one to the main site. I just wanted to add a web-part onto the page rather than a full app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, when you add a web-part or app-part you are creating an embedded version of an existing app rather than a brand new app. So while they are very functional by themselves, in many cases you can't add an web/app-part to a page if that app does not already exist in the same site/sub-site.

If you create a Promoted Links list (even if you hide it) then you can add a app/web-part to your page. One thing to note though is that the web-part/app-part that you add will be linked to the source app. So if you plan on adding several of them to various pages, a good practice would be to create views in the original Promoted Links list for what you want to show on each page you add the web-part/app-part to. That way you can use the one list for everywhere.

Comment: this has worked to let me add the app-part. Thanks for the suggestion about views, that saved me the trouble of creating multiple apps

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge there are typically 2 reasons why you can't create a promoted links app/list.

- you must enable `team collaboration lists` feature
- if you use a custom master page, make sure that the following place holders are being rendered

> asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea"
>   runat="server"
>
> asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBar" runat="server"

Further reading:

http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2013/08/missing-apps-you-can-add-with-custom-master-page-in-sharepoint-2013/#more-2483

Comment: I can add the app itself when I click the gear icon and select Add App. I just can't add an App Part to a page (like a Wiki page) unless there is already an existing Promoted Links app

Comment: it sounds like what we'd expect. if you want to add a web part / list view / slider part the list with content needs to exist first.